# What is the difference between PHP soapClient and .net soap?

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I have an issue with consume a .NET webservice in PHP. I have tried with the built in SoapClient and Zend Framework SoapClient.
When i POST the message to the webservice as XML using CURL i get the correct response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap12:Body>
             <Authenticate xmlns="http://xxxxx"></Authenticate>
        </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

But when i try PHPs SoapClient or Zend Framework SoapClient it creates the following envelope, which does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxx">
        <env:Body>
            <ns1:Authenticate/>
        </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

I can clearly see that the envelopes differ, but why? 
Where is the formatting specified in the WSDL? 
How can i get PHP SoapClient to create envelopes with correct XML formatting?
It surley cant be so that as a developer I'm supposed to "guess" what format a webservice want its envelope?
What are these two different SOAP envelopes called?

Lastly, this isnt the first time i encountered this problem. Usually its fixed with combinations of PHP built in SoapClient, Zend SoapClient, NuSOAP or another library. But it's so incredibly annoying to always have these SOAP battles.

Comment: Why do you think second response is incorrect? Only difference is that namespaces are defined in different parts of document, but response is valid.

Comment: Second is wrong because the webservice returns a 400 response code,  Client error or similar. The differences are not only where namespace is defined, but also the names of the keys.

Comment: From what i can see in first request Authenticate is being sent as empty string, in second it's null. Probably Schema doesn't allow nulls. How do you pass parametrs to PHP soap client invocation?

Comment: Yes, you are correct there. But it does not matter, i get the same error even if i fill the authenticate parameter. I still dont understand why the keys in the xml are different. When i use the correct keys, it all works. What are the difference between PHP soap implementation and .NET soap implementation?

Comment: You mean namespaces? It shouldn't matter - it's only used for transporting and decoding soap message. Both SoapClient and SoapServer are parsing it to/from objects.